# Core ML iOS 11 not recognizing images properly

Tags: swift, image-recognition, ios11, coreml

I tried Core ML which was recently introduced in iOS to recognise and classify images. The problem is, it is not giving proper results for the images sent.

If i send an earth image(Globe) it is giving me the class as bubble. Below is the code i used,

```
            let model = Resnet50()

            let pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer =  (modelImg.pixelBuffer())!

            if let prediction = try? model.prediction(image: pixelBuffer) {
                print( "Found it!! It is a/an \(prediction.classLabel)")
            }
```

Is it possible to train the Model with custom use cases on top of the existing Core ML model?(For ex. Resnet50)

Comment: IN addition to the accepted answer, one more thing to keep in mind - in CoreML a trained model cannot be updated without an app update. I lost a link to a blog about what CoreML *isn't*, but I've found a good resource for using CoreML tools to be this repo's README: https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core ML can only be used for inference with already trained models. You will have to use some other tool to previously train your model, and then convert it to Core ML, using Core ML Tools. You can find the supported third-party machine learning tools and formats in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/converting_trained_models_to_core_ml

Comment: So there is no way to train existing ML models?

Comment: Not using Core ML. Core ML can only use existing trained models. It's meant as a fast framework for on device inference.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Matusalem's answer, when using an image classification network you can only get back results in one of the classes it was trained against. In this case, you appear to be using the pretrained ResNet50 Core ML model that Apple [has made available for download](https://developer.apple.com/machine-learning/).

That image classification network, like many others you'll find out there, has been trained on the ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge 2012 dataset, commonly referred to as ImageNet or ILSVRC2012. That dataset became the benchmark for convolutional neural network designs after the 2012 competition, so you'll find many pretrained networks using it. It has 1000 categories of things it can identify in images, with the full listing of labels [here](https://gist.github.com/yrevar/942d3a0ac09ec9e5eb3a). You'll note that "globe" is not among those, so the network will provide the closest matching category of those it has been trained against.

If you'd never seen a globe before, or even been exposed to the word "globe", would you be able to identify one? These networks can generalize in surprising ways, but if they don't even have categories for what you want to classify, they're not going to be able to provide the results you want.

The ImageNet dataset is an interesting starting point, but probably isn't the best for real-world use. It has an odd distribution of classes, with something like 200 breeds of dog but no humans. It can be a great starting point for pretraining a network, and then using transfer learning to refine that network to your particular dataset, but you'll most likely want to train your own application-specific network. That's a whole other topic.

Comment: Brad, your answers always put a smile on my face for some reason!